# Background color not visible in Safari

Tags: html, css

```css
.chevron {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 12px;
      margin-bottom: 6px;
    }
.chevron:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 40px;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 60%;
        background-color: rgb(9, 73, 131);
      background-color: rgba(9, 73, 131, 1);
      transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
        -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
        -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
        -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
    }
.chevron:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 40px;
      right: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 60%;
        background-color: rgb(9, 73, 131);
      background-color: rgba(9, 73, 131, 1);
      transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
        -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
        -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
        -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
    }
```

I have a Wordpress Project where I have added a Background color. The Background color work fine with all the browsers except Safari. I have tried multiple approaches like giving rgb(For Old Browsers) rgba(For Latest Browsers) but it is still not visible.

Comment: please paste your css code here

Comment: @LokeshThakur added the CSS code.

Comment: AND relevant HTML!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below CSS for safari browser.

```
_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .chevron:before{
    background-color: rgb(9, 73, 131);
}
_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .chevron:after{
    background-color: rgb(9, 73, 131);
}
```

Comment: There is a specific section in project for which I need the background color and not for whole page.